# Fetch api issue with DELETE - changes to OPTIONS even when cors is good

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, cors, fetch-api

Using fetch api in the client browser, I am not having issues with GET or POST, but I am having issues with fetch and DELETE. Its seems to change the DELETE request method to OPTIONS.

Most of the research shows to be a cors issues, but with me I have the cors issues covered.

I am not sure if this is a [valid fetch spec api link](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#methods) but it shows:

> A CORS-safe listed method is a method that is `GET`, `HEAD`, or `POST`.

I am not sure if this means I can not use DELETE on fetch with cors and this is why I am having issues?

browser code:

```
var request =
          new Request(url, {
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'DELETE'
          });

        return fetch(request)
          .then(this.fetchError.bind(this))
          .then(this.json)
          .then((response)=> {
            this.set(`uploadState.${index}.value`, false);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      },
```

---

chrome network tab:

```
Request URL:http://72.12.4.3:9000/api/v1/listings/3/47/image-3-47-1492565415145.jpeg
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:72.12.4.3:9000

Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://72.12.4.3:8000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:25
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 19 Apr 2017 01:36:07 GMT
ETag:W/"19-9NCRiMyz+z1Bt6fGQfcxA"
X-Powered-By:Express

Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:
Access-Control-Request-Method:DELETE
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:72.12.4.3:9000
If-None-Match:W/"19-9NCRiMyz+z1Bt6fGQfcxA"
Origin:http://72.12.4.3:8000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://72.12.4.3:8000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OPTIONS` request is expected and basically is the mechanism that the browser uses to check if the request `DELETE` in this case is allowed.

The `OPTIONS` request seems to get a `401 Unauthorized` response from your server. This would indeed cause the request to fail. Respond with `200 OK` instead.

As an aside, the header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:` is wrong, but this shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: To configure a node backend to handle the `OPTIONS` request, the `cors` npm package can be installed, and instructions for configuring it are at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight